# Why does webpack HMR require the current directory in the module path?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My webpack configuration compiles just fine, but when I try to edit my CSS (stylus) files with hot module replacement, it crashes with this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/stylus-loader!./src/pages/login/login.styl
>   Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/vagrant/client/src/pages/login/login.styl'
>       at Error (native)

I noticed the path `./src/pages/login/login.styl` in the error message and tried adding the current working directory to the module path in the webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve('./'),   // <- THIS
        path.resolve('./src'),
        path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.coffee']
},
```

And now it works fine. I don't really want to add the whole project folder as a module though, I'd rather HMR didn't act weird.

Is this simply expected behavior from HMR?

---

I suspect `style-loader` might actually be the culprit here, since I don't see it in the loader chain in the error message. Here's the loader config for `.styl` files:

```
{
    test: new RegExp('\.styl$'),
    loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
},
```

Perhaps it's a bug?